# Render Passes File Output in Headless Mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, command-line, render-passes

Here is the blender manual on command line rendering: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html

I am having an issue in blender where blender hangs on rendering in UI mode. I can't even render an image - well I can usually render one image any subsequent attempts hangs blender on initialisation. This is both Eevee and Cycles and happens in most files but not all.

However, blender renders perfectly fine in command line mode.

I am trying to render out a scene with render passes and I have set up a file output in the compositor to render out to OpenEXR. But when I render the animation in the command line, only the composited image is rendered, not the passes. I am wondering (now that I am writing this) do I have to disconnect the image from the composite output?

What is the process for rendering via command line for render passes?